# Show that $(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C') \subset A \cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that

$$(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C') \subset A \cup B$$

So far I got:

$$(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C') \subseteq (A \cup C \cup B) \cap (B \cup C' \cup A)$$
$$(A \cup B \cup C) \cap (A \cup B \cup C') = A \cup B$$
$$(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C') \subseteq A \cup B$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (the applied) equality $(P\cup C)\cap(P\cup C')=P$ has already been proved earlier then your proof is okay.

---

Alternative:

Let it be that $x\notin A\cup B$ or equivalently that $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$.

Evidently $x\notin C$ or $x\notin C'$.

If $x\notin C$ then $x\notin A\cup C$, and if $x\notin C'$ then $x\notin B\cup C'$.

So in both cases: $x\notin (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup C')$.

Proved is now: $$x\notin A\cup B\implies x\notin (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup C')$$
or equivalently: $$x\in (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup C')\implies x\in A\cup B$$
This is true for every $x$ so we are allowed to conclude that:$$(A\cup C)\cap (B\cup C')\subseteq A\cup B$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but to me that solution isn't what I would have done in the first place (but then we all are a bit different).

What I would have done is to use the distributive laws:

$$(A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C') = (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C') \cup (C\cap B)\cup (C\cap C') $$

Now $A\cap B\subseteq A$ (or B), $A\cap C'\subseteq A$, $C\cap B\subseteq B$ and $C\cap C' = \emptyset \subseteq A$ (or B). This means that all of these are subsets of $A\cup B$ and unions of subsets are still a subset.